# How to use CORS to access an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cors

When a user prints, my server generate a PDF, and I do this to show the print dialog for the PDF.

```
$('<iframe type="application/pdf"></iframe>').attr('src', url).load(function() {
    var iframe = this;
    setTimeout(function() { //Chrome PDF viewer shows "Loading..." forever otherwise
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
        $(iframe).remove(); //gc
    }, 50);
}).appendTo('body');
```

But now I am hosting the PDFs on S3. I get

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost" from
accessing a frame with origin "https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com".
Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I presume I need to add [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS) headers.

I have

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Did you resolve this? If so, can you post your answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Answer (score 35):

CORS does not apply when attempting to programmatically access content from a cross-origin iframe.  If you want to access content from an iframe on a different domain, you will need to make use of the Web Messaging API (`window.postMessage` & the `onmessage` event) to communicate between your page and the iframe.

Comment: That would be okay...except it seems my problem had no solution. In the iframe I have a *PDF*. And I want to print it. I can't exactly use `window.postMessage` in a PDF.

Comment: @PaulDraper Just attach the PDF to an `<embed>` in the iframe, and include your message passing code in the iframe itself.

Comment: @Ray, could you explain it with code? I'm a little lost here. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why CORS don't apply to cross-origin iframes. If the contents of an iframe explicitly allow access from another origin, why are iframes excluded from this?

Comment: [`window.postMessage` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: @SebastianZartner Because iframe "lives" — the user can interact with it, add some information, for example

Comment: Interactions by the user with the content of the iframe are not the issue. By setting the CORS header, the page within the iframe provides full access to the page including the iframe. And I guess, that can cause security issues, because the accessing page could be corrupted and so manipulate the contents of the iframe's page. And that's why `window.postMessage()` exists, providing restricted interaction between both. But maybe that's what you meant. :-)

Comment: I think why cors is not supported in iframe is because iframe is a new window context, by allowing full control on that window, you are also giving access to any future website, which gets loaded inside iframe with location.href, and that website might not want to give access.

Answer (score 0):

Having the reference to the top window, you can create programmatically a script and set it's innerHTML to what you want to execute. After that you can append it on top window's document head and the browser will execute it.