# How to set <iframe> in angular

Tags: angular, iframe, angular9

I am using iframe for loading the hyperlink for mweb and mobile in case of desktop directly opening the url Even though I am using pipe didn't solve the error.It is giving

Refused to display 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

This is how I used in html

```
<div [innerHTML]="pdfUrl | safe: 'html'" #dynamicView></div>
```

ts code

```
`<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
        frameborder="0"  target='_top' width="` + screen.width + 'px' + `" height="` + screen.height + 'px' + `"></iframe>`;
```

Comment: you can't display the url in frame, which is differ from your parent url.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to resolve iframe cross domain issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866219/how-to-resolve-iframe-cross-domain-issue)