# Link in iframe ok, but does not display in embedded page

Tags: html, iframe, embedded-resource

I am trying to embed a map into a travel blog using an iframe.  The underlying web page is fine, but it doesn't display in the iframe.  I suspect it is a size problem, and I've tried adjusting various parameters.  Does anyone know what I can try next?

I am able to recreate the problem under jsfiddle.

```html
<iframe src="https://trackmytour.com/cgkvp/e" width="100%" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black;">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from the console when trying to load that iframe :

> Cross-Origin request blocked: The Same-Origin-Rule forbids reading of the extern resource at https://trackmytour.com/static/vue/js/chunk-vendors.2eefddd2.js. (Reason: CORS-Header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Thats the reason that you cannot see it in the iframe.
More details about that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40866219/14909980). If you are not the owner of the website and have access to the webserver, there is no way to circumvent this problem : What you are trying to do **is not possible**, sorry ...

Comment: Thanks. I missed that message.