# "this content cannot be displayed in a frame" in IE after server moved(same domain)

Tags: java, internet-explorer, server, cross-domain

Domain A site(aaa.example.com) have iframe of B site (bbb.example.com)
Recently, I moved the server from other services to AWS.
And A site previous B site and moved B site are all different location.
Example like moved B in AWS, A site in Digital ocean, and previous B site is other...
Before moving the server, it is works in IE. But suddenly show "this content cannot be displayed in a frame" Nginx setting and etc all same.
Any idea why like this and how to fix it?
Is it a firework problem?
Please help me...
Oh, all https

Comment: Hi, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Once you move one site it to another domain you start dealing with cross origin issues. You can take a look at https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b for more details on how to potentially deal with it.

Here is another stack overflow entry on the topic: [how to resolve iframe cross domain issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866219/how-to-resolve-iframe-cross-domain-issue)

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, try to add `<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">` to the webpage that you want to show in an `Iframe`.
See whether it works.

If the issue still persists then try to add `add_header X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM "url";` to your Nginx server can help to fix this issue.